# Titanium ImageView can't scale the size by setting the height and width properties?

Tags: imageview, titanium

I'm trying to display an image as the background of my app, and I try to use an ImageView, the code blew:

```
            bg-img = TUI.create-image-view({
            image: ev.media
            left: 0
            top: 0
            border-width: 2
            border-color: "red"
            # width: img-width + "px"
            # height: img-height + "px"
            })
        bg-img.width =  2754 
        bg-img.height = 4896 
        # pic-img.add bg-img
        bg-img.add-event-listener \click, !(ev)->
            log \clicked-on-pic-img
            _this.trigger \click-edit-pic-view, ev
        # # inspect pic-img
        _this.Els.pic-container.add  bg-img
```

The image doesn't apear in the screen, but If I minus the size of bg-img like:

```
                bg-img = TUI.create-image-view({
            image: ev.media
            left: 0
            top: 0
            border-width: 2
            border-color: "red"
            # width: img-width + "px"
            # height: img-height + "px"
            })
        bg-img.width =  2754 / 3
        bg-img.height = 4896 / 3
        # pic-img.add bg-img
        bg-img.add-event-listener \click, !(ev)->
            log \clicked-on-pic-img
            _this.trigger \click-edit-pic-view, ev
        # # inspect pic-img
        _this.Els.pic-container.add  bg-img
```

It can't run correctly,  I don't why? o(╯□╰)o
some one can help? Thx!

Comment: Could you please display the actual code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

my origin code is blew, And my purpose is to dynamic get a image from photogallary, and set the img as a backgroundimage of a View whose size is decided by the image: 
(and I use the  https://github.com/6174/TiDraggable  module)

```
create-pic-view.bind \photo-gallery, ->
_this = @
log \open-photo-gallery
Ti.Media.open-photo-gallery({
    success: !(ev)->
        log \success-get-image-event
        # inspect ev
        #image size in pixels
        img-width =  ev.width 
        img-height = ev.height  
        # convertPointToView( Point point, Titanium.UI.View destinationView ) : Point
        # Translates a point from this view's coordinate system to another view's coordinate system.
        pic-img = _this.Els.pic-img =  draggable.create-view({
            background-image: ev.media.native-path
            top: 0
            left:  0
            width: img-width  
            height: img-height  
            }) 
        pic-img.add-event-listener \click, !(ev)->
            log \clicked-on-pic-img
            _this.trigger \click-edit-pic-view, ev
        _this.Els.pic-container.add  pic-img    
    })
```

Comment: when the image is small like 480X640 It can run correctly, But if the image is larger like 1200X3600.  The background-image won't display!!